# Problem - For loops only fill the first position of 2d array instead of whole 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

so I want to replace some elements in my 2d array. This is the grid I already created:

```
Row 0: OOxxxOx
Row 1: xxxxxxx
Row 2: xOxOOxO
Row 3: xxxxxOO
Row 4: xxOxOxO
Row 5: OxOxxxO
```

I want to replace all the "O" with ".", this I call Bomb explode. When the bombs "explode", the ones left, right, above and under the element will change to "." as well. This is my code for "Bomb exploding" : (The try catch is there so my code can just move on even if there is array index out of bounds)

```
          try {

            for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                    if (grid[i][j].equals(oldBomb)) {
                        grid[i][j] = empty;
                        grid[i][j + 1] = empty;
                        grid[i][j - 1] = empty;
                        grid[i + 1][j] = empty;
                        grid[i - 1][j] = empty;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
```

The code will give me this ouput (The grid on top is the grid I created before):

```
Row 0: OxxOxxO
Row 1: OxxOOOO
Row 2: OxxOOxO
Row 3: OOxxxOx
Row 4: OxxOOxx
Row 5: OOxOOOx

Row 0: ..xOxxO
Row 1: OxxOOOO
Row 2: OxxOOxO
Row 3: OOxxxOx
Row 4: OxxOOxx
Row 5: OOxOOOx
```

As you can see only the first bomb explodes but the other's don't.
Can please anyone help me why only one element changes and not the others?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running here: https://onlinegdb.com/Bkg7lCDqLI

```
 import java.io.*;
    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {


char playground[][]={{'0','0','x','x','x','0','x'},
{'x','x','x','x','x','x','x'},
{'x','0','x','0','0','0','0'},
{'x','x','x','x','x','0','0'},
{'x','x','0','x','0','x','0'},
{'0','x','0','x','x','x','0'}};
System.out.println("Current status of playground");
int rows=6,cols=7;
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){

    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
        System.out.print(playground[i][j]+"  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("Placing bombs now ...boomm");
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){

    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
        if(playground[i][j]=='0'){
            playground[i][j]='.'; 

            if (!(i - 1 < 0) && playground[i - 1][j]=='x') {
                playground[i - 1][j]='.';
            }
            if (!(i + 1 > rows-1) && playground[i + 1][j]=='x') {
                playground[i + 1][j]='.';
            }
            if (!(j - 1 < 0) && playground[i][j-1]=='x') {
            playground[i][j - 1]='.';
            }
            if (!(j + 1 > cols-1) && playground[i][j+1]=='x') {
            playground[i][j + 1]='.';
            }

        }
    }
};
System.out.println("After bomb blast");
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){

    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
        System.out.print(playground[i][j]+"  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The try catch is there so my code can just move on even if there is array index out of bounds

That's bad design. Use if-statements instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
        if (grid[i][j].equals(oldBomb)) {
            grid[i][j] = empty;

            if (j + 1 < grid[i].length)
                grid[i][j + 1] = empty;

            if (j > 0)
                grid[i][j - 1] = empty;

            if (i + 1 < grid.length)
                grid[i + 1][j] = empty;

            if (i > 0)
                grid[i - 1][j] = empty;
        }
    }
}
```